# Can't find my UIApplicationDelegate anywhere swift

Tags: ios, swift

#### Problem:

Unable to `UIApplicationDelegate` file

I would like to connect firebase to my new app but can't locate the `UIApplication` file.

Comment: Are you using the new SwiftUI application lifecycle?

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new project the life cycle which can either be `SwiftUI App` or `UIKit App Delegate`.

For the SwiftUI app you might have chosen `SwiftUI App` as the life cycle, which might be the reason why you can't see `UIApplicationDelegate`

There are possible options:

1. In the App struct declare a model as `@StateObject` and use that to use the model to connect to firebase
2. Or Create a new project using the `UIKit App Delegate`

[image: Xcode New Project Life Cycle]